# Test for START_STICKY in a service

Tags: android, testing, android-service

I have an app which consists of a long running service. I have returned START_STICKY from onStartCommand method of this service. Now i want to test whether START_STICKY is working properly or not. So how can i test the scenario that my service is killed by the android OS due to less memory and it is restarted by the android OS and onStartCommand method is called again. i cannot afford to wait for hours to test this scenario. Please suggest a way out.

Answer (score 3):

You could try killing the process from DDMS. The OS might restart it in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try killing the service using task Killer (if you are testing on phone)