# Test START_STICKY service

Tags: android, android-service

> I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740580/test-for-start-sticky-in-a-service) answer and it's not useful in my case.

I have create a simple service, it does nothing but logs method names. I run it from my activity and kill it by using

```
adb shell am stopservice -n serviceComponent
```

`onDestroy()` is called on service. Now as I have returned `Service.START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`; I wait for the system to restart 
the service and it **never** restarts.

Is this the right behavior? I have gone through [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63793) issue but couldn't find a reliable answer.

```
public class SampleService extends Service {

    private static final boolean LOG = true;

    public static final String CALLER = "sample.service.caller";

    /**
     * called once when service is created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(LOG){
            log("onCreate() -> thread: %s", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    } // onCreate

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(LOG){
            log(">>>>>> onStartCommand()");
        }
        if(LOG){
            log("thread: %s", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

        if(LOG){
            log("caller[%s]", intent.getStringExtra(CALLER));
        }

        if(LOG){
            log("<<<<<< onStartCommand()");
        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    } // onStartCommand

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(LOG){
            log("onDestroy() -> thread: %s", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "destroying", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } // onDestroy


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    } // onBind

    private void log(String format, Object... args){
        Utils.log("SampleService", String.format(format, args));
    } // log

} // SampleService
```

**Here is what I have tried so far**

- I start the service by calling using this code

  ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleService.class);
  intent.putExtra(SampleService.CALLER, "main activity");
  if(null == startService(intent)){
      if(LOG){
          log("startService -> %s", "service not found!");
      }

  } //
  ```
- After starting service, `adb shell dumpsys activity services | grep "com.mallaudin"` returns this

  ```
  ServiceRecord{8bc884d u0 com.mallaudin.services/.SampleService}
  intent={cmp=com.mallaudin.services/.SampleService}
  packageName=com.mallaudin.services
  processName=com.mallaudin.services
  baseDir=/data/app/com.mallaudin.services-2/base.apk
  dataDir=/data/user/0/com.mallaudin.services
  app=ProcessRecord{b1c1c5a 32017:com.mallaudin.services/u0a94}
  ```
- Now I stop service by invoking `adb shell am stopservice -n com.mallaudin.services/.SampleService`. It stops the service and `onDestroy` is 
  called. Same behaviour is observe when I kill the service from services list in my phone.

  ```
  Stopping service: Intent { cmp=com.mallaudin.services/.SampleService }
  Service stopped
  ```
- When I use `adb shell force-stop com.mallaudin.services` command, service is stopped but `onDestroy()` is not called.

Comment: I used  `adb shell am kill com.mallaudin.services` to kill the app. It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`START_STICKY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) documentation:

> ... if this service's process is killed while it is started...

`adb shell am stopservice` and `context.stopService(Intent)` don't actually kill the service process, but rather just stops the service while keeping the app process running. So the system won't restart the service in this case.

You can try the following: create an app with an `Activity` and a `Service`. Then start the activity, start the service, and kill the app by sliding it from the overview screen (aka the recents menu). Your service should restart.

Comment: I have tested it by `adb shell am fore-stop` which kills the process. Also I have killed the service from services menu.

Comment: If it doesn't kill the service then why `onDestroy` is being called? I don't really get what's happening!

Comment: @mallaudin i'm not sure if `force-stop` kills the process, but i'm positive that `kill` does. Note that `kill` doesn't work on apps on foreground

Comment: @mallaudin `onDestroy` is being called because the service is being stopped. Note that sometimes when the process is killed `onDestroy` is not called

Comment: I think you are right. I am using `kill` command and it seems to work now. Let me confirm it and I will accept your answer.

Comment: i'm having the same problem. onDestroy is not being called sometimes with START_STICKY . Does any body else have a clue why?